# validation is not working in simple html form

Tags: javascript, html, validation

i have made a small code for html form and trying to validate it with javascript but it is not working and not even giving any error...
I am not getting whats the problem behind....
i have seen [javascript simple validation not working?

here is my code..

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>A simple Input Form</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function validateEmail() {
    //var emailID = document.myForm.email.value;
    if(!validateNonEmpty(inputField, helpText))
        return false;
    return validateRegEx(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/, inputField.value, helpText, 
            "please enter an email address i.e. johndoe@acme.com");
    }
function validatedob(inputField, helpText){
    if(!validateNonEmpty(inputField, helpText))
        return false;
    return validateRegEx(/^\d{2}\/\d{2}\/\d{4}$/, inputField.value, helpText, 
            "please enter an email address i.e. johndoe@acme.com");
}
function age(){
    var currentDate = new Date()
    var day = currentDate.getDay()
    var month = currentDate.getMonth() + 1
    var year = currentDate.getFullYear()

}
function formValidate(){
     if( document.myForm.dob.value == "" )
       {
         alert( "Please provide your date of birth!" );
         document.myForm.dob.focus() ;
         return false;
       }
     else {
         var dateformat = validatedate();
         if (dateformat == false)
             {
                return false;
             }
     }
       if( document.myForm.email.value == "" )
       {
         alert( "Please provide your Email!" );
         document.myForm.email.focus() ;
         return false;
       }else{
         var ret = validateEmail();
         if( ret == false )
         {
              return false;
         }
       }
       if (document.myForm.age.value="")
           {
            alert("please provide your age");
            document.myForm.age.focus();
            return false;
           }
       else
           {
       var ageformat = validateage();
       if (ageformat == false)
           {
            return false;
           }
           }
}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="left">
<input type="button" value="previous">
<img src="/images/jump2" alt="Just-in-time" />
</div>
<input type="button" value="next">
    <form name="myForm" method="post" action="success.html" onsubmit="formValidate();">
         Date of Birth: <input id="dob" type="text" name="dob" size=10><br>
         Age: <input id="age" type="text" name="age"><br>
         Email: <input id="email" type="text" name="email"><br>
         <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you produce a fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

And add `method="post"` to your `form` tag.

Comment: Meaning it still doesn't work? Can you post your updated code in your original question?

Comment: yeap still not working, just updated code in original question.

Comment: It has to do with your if / else construction in the formValidate function. It's probably easier to use a switch: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp

Comment: I made this fiddle for you, please use the comments as a reference. Your code is one big mess. I left out the switch for now, just to keep it as simple as possible. Use google to further improve your code and please think logically about why things do not work (things that don't exists can never work for instance): http://jsfiddle.net/sDMUu/

Comment: I forgot to comment that you never give any value to these parameters: `validatedob(inputField, helpText)`.

Answer (score 1):

Change this in formValidate()

`document.myForm.Name.value == ""` to `document.myForm.dob.value == ""`

```
document.myForm.EMail.value == "" to document.myForm.email.value == ""
```

**Do not use**

```
 document.write("<b>" + day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "</b>");
```

It will replace the whole contents of your body

Comment: then how i will use the regex i have created to match and validate?

Comment: @amy You have no form element whoose name="name" or name="EMail", Check your html code

Answer (score 1):

First of all,in your `formValidate(),`

**First** if condition is incorrect.Your form does not have a "name" element, it should either be "dob" or "age" or "value".

**Secondly**, in the second if instead of this 
`if( document.myForm.EMail.value == "" )`, it should be `if( document.myForm.email.value == "" )`.

Comment: yeap checked corrected.... but why email validation is not working... i have created a regex too...